# How to use simpledb appender using Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, amazon-simpledb

How to log to amazon simple db using log4j properties

```
http://code.google.com/p/simpledb-appender/
```

This site demos how to configure simpledb using slf4j using xml file, but i require the same with log4j properties, is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, See below

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, simpledb

# Direct log messages to simpledb
log4j.appender.simpledb=com.kikini.logging.simpledb.SimpleDBAppender
log4j.appender.simpledb.DomainName=your_simpledb_domain
log4j.appender.simpledb.AccessId=your_aws_access_id
log4j.appender.simpledb.SecretKey=your_aws_secret_key
```

Comment: can you tell what exactly is simpledb?\

Comment: It's a NoSQL database managed by Amazon as part of the Amazon Web Services. See more at http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Comment: i am getting the following error                                                    log4j:ERROR A "com.kikini.logging.simpledb.SimpleDBAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7a9664a1] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "com.kikini.logging.simpledb.SimpleDBAppender" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7a9664a1].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "simpledb".

Comment: it is usually customary to open a new question in such cases. My guess here is that the simpledb-appender jar is not in the classpath